# Docker swarm cluster how to add manager nodes as a reachable

Tags: docker-swarm

I am using docker virtual box for windows 7 machine.

```
$ docker-machine ls
```

NAME       ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
default    *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://1.2.3.101:2376           v17.04.0-ce
manager1   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://1.2.3.106:2376           v17.04.0-ce
manager2   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://1.2.3.105:2376           v17.04.0-ce
worker1    -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://1.2.3.102:2376           v17.04.0-ce
worker2    -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://1.2.3.104:2376           v17.04.0-ce
worker3    -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://1.2.3.103:2376           v17.04.0-ce

```
$ docker node ls
```

ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS
e8kum3w0xqd4g02cx1tfps9ni     manager1            Down                Active
aibbgvqtiv9bhzbs8l20lbx2m *   default             Ready               Active              Leader
sbt75u8ayvf7lqj7y3zppjwvk     worker1             Ready               Active
ny2j5556w4tyflf3tjfqzjrte     worker2             Ready               Active
veipdd0qs2gjnogftxvr1kfhq     worker3             Ready               Active

Now i am planing set up environment docker swarm cluster, like i have three manager node (name as default,manager1,manager2) and three workers nodes (name as worker1, worker2,worker3).

Using default manager node i init docker swarm with address

```
$ docker swarm init --advertise-addr 1.2.3.101:2376
```

## output starting

Swarm initialized: current node (acbbgvqtiv6bhzbs8l20lbx1e) is now a manager.

To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-1ie1b420bhs452ubt4iy01brfc97801q0ya608spbt0fnuzkp0-1h2a86acczxe4qta164np487r 1.2.3.101:2377

To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.

## output ending

Using this output i easily added worker nodes. Now my question is how yo add other manager (manager1,manager2) to **reachable** state. Note still default node act as **leader**

could you please any one help on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer.

On the existing manager host get manager-token:

```
>docker swarm join-token manager
```

and then on a potential manager host execute got output

Answer (score 1):

Run command on manager node 
docker swarm join-token manager
to get the token to add other nodes as manager, should be similar to the worker token you got above
You need to ssh to the other machine which you want to add as a manager node to the swarm.
Once done, run that command

For the manager to advertise address you can provide --advertise-addr and --listen-addr flags as well, they take host:port as param.
Hope this helps

Comment: Isn't it the same answer?